# parameterize azure storage account name in spark cluster config databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

wondering if this is to parameterize the azure storage account name part in the spark cluster config in Databricks?

I have a working example where the values are referencing secret scopes:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<azurestorageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/sp-id}}
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<azurestorageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<azurestorageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/05646f53-5e81-4a6a-85f5-a1ee2189bea4/oauth2/token
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.<azurestorageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<azurestorageaccountname>.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/sp-secret}}
```

But this does not work if I try it on the keys:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.{{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/azurestorageaccountname}}.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/sp-id}}
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/azurestorageaccountname}}.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.{{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/azurestorageaccountname}}.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/05646f53-5e81-4a6a-85f5-a1ee2189bea4/oauth2/token
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.{{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/azurestorageaccountname}}.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.{{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/azurestorageaccountname}}.dfs.core.windows.net {{secrets/keyvault_secret_scope/sp-secret}}
```

If it is impossible how can you replace the cluster config between environments? I need the azure storage account name to be different in DEV vs PROD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If configuring a specific storage account is not a must have requirement then you may try following. In my case I had a Service Principal that has access to more than one Storage Accounts and my Data Brick cluster config looks like following to use oAuth2. I am using an AKV to store my ClientId and Secret along with a secret scope. I also noticed that you mentioned different Storage Account names in diff environments. This will be taken care automatically as you are not defining a specific SAs but whichever SAs has appropriate permissions your cluster would honour that.
Please excuse me if Its not helpful as this is my first post here.

**fs.azure.account.auth.type OAuth
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id {{secrets/akv-xx-xx-db2akv-scope/akv-ak-databricks-clientid}}
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret {{secrets/akv-xx-xx-db2akv-scope/akv-ak-databricks-secret}}
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx/oauth2/token**

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out that I could just remove the specific endpoint and have the credentials be generic as you mentioned!